# -i flag for GHC works from command line but does not work from OPTIONS_GHC

Tags: haskell, import, importerror, ghc, compiler-flags

I have folder `A`, which contains folders `B` and `C`. Folder `B` contains file `B.hs`

```
module B where
```

Folder `C` contains file `C.hs`

```
module C where
  import B
```

Everything works when I compile `C.hs` with command

```
ghc C.hs -i"..\B"
```

Then I tried to add the option to `C.hs`

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -i..\B #-}
```

That, however, does not work. Neither does

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -i"..\B" #-}
```

The other flags like `-Wall` and `-v` work just fine. I know that some flags are static and can only be used from the command line. I found some contradictory information about the `-i` flag. One piece of documentation claims that it's [static](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html), another one that it's [dynamic](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html). Is it possible to make the `-i` flag work from `OPTIONS_GHC`, and if yes, how?

Comment: Even if this is possible, I don't think it's a good idea, since `..\B` would be (I guess) a path relative to the current directory of the GHC process, which can differ from the directory of the source file. If you need to specify such paths, maybe you should consider using Cabal or stack and their config files.

Comment: But isn't it interesting why? I would like to know if it's a fundamental limitation of OPTIONS_GHC (and if yes then why exactly) or if it's possible to make it work (and if yes then how). It bothers me because it looks like it should work - so there's probably something I don't understand about OPTIONS_GHC, and I'd like to learn what it is.

Comment: Sure, I'd also like to know why (hence my upvote). Still, my guess is that the answer is that (almost) nobody requested this flag to be implemented as dynamic, so the devs focused on more important features.